# Reset select option based on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to reset my select options if I click other radio button that doesn't trigger the select div.

Here's my sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').on('change', function() {
    var title = $(this).val(); // Get radio value
    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'theme2') {
      $('.occ_select').addClass('l').removeClass('off');
    } else { //...otherwise status of radio is off
      $('.occ_select').removeClass('l').addClass('off');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br> <input type="radio" id="theme1" name="cake_theme" value="dedi" /> Dedication
<br> <input type="radio" id="theme2" name="cake_theme" value="occ" /> Others

<div id="occassion" class="occ_select off">
  <select name="occassion_select" id="occa_slct">
     <option disabled selected value>-- Select one --</option>
     <option value="otheerrr"> otheerrr </option>
     <option value="other1"> other1 </option>
     <option value="other2"> other2 </option>
 </select>
</div>
```

So what I would like to happen, that everytime I choose "dedication button" , the select option will reset to `<option disabled selected value>-- Select one --</option>`. I don't know what am I missing in my jQuery to trigger that reset event.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `val('')` to reset the value of the select to it's default. I'd also suggest that you disable the `select` unless the appropriate radio input is selected so that the user knows an option is required. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').on('change', function() {
    var title = $(this).val();
    
    if (this.id === 'theme2') {
      $('.occ_select').addClass('l').removeClass('off');
      $('#occa_slct').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('.occ_select').removeClass('l').addClass('off');
      
      $('#occa_slct').prop('disabled', true).val(''); // reset value here
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br> 
<input type="radio" id="theme1" name="cake_theme" value="dedi" /> Dedication<br> 
<input type="radio" id="theme2" name="cake_theme" value="occ" /> Others

<div id="occassion" class="occ_select off">
  <select name="occassion_select" id="occa_slct" disabled="disabled">
     <option disabled selected value>-- Select one --</option>
     <option value="otheerrr"> otheerrr </option>
     <option value="other1"> other1 </option>
     <option value="other2"> other2 </option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, that was quick, exactly that it also resets in the other button.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').on('change', function() {
    var title = $(this).val(); // Get radio value
    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'theme2') {
      $('.occ_select').addClass('l').removeClass('off');
    } else { //...otherwise status of radio is off
      $('.occ_select').removeClass('l').addClass('off');
    }

    $("#occa_slct option").eq(0).prop("selected", title == "dedi") //set to first option when value of title is dedi
    $("#occa_slct").prop("disabled", title == "dedi") //disable select when value of title is dedi
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br> <input type="radio" id="theme1" name="cake_theme" value="dedi" /> Dedication
<br> <input type="radio" id="theme2" name="cake_theme" value="occ" /> Others


<div id="occassion" class="occ_select off">
  <select name="occassion_select" id="occa_slct">
     <option disabled selected value>-- Select one --</option>
     <option value="otheerrr"> otheerrr </option>
     <option value="other1"> other1 </option>
     <option value="other2"> other2 </option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This selects `otherrrr` as the value, not `-- Select one --`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <br> <input type="radio" id="theme1" name="cake_theme" value="dedi" />  Dedication
    <br> <input type="radio" id="theme2" name="cake_theme" value="occ" /> Others


    <div id="occassion" class="occ_select off">
        <select name="occassion_select" id="occa_slct">
            <option disabled selected value="0">-- Select one --</option>
            <option value="otheerrr"> otheerrr </option>
            <option value="other1"> other1 </option>
            <option value="other2"> other2 </option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

and JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(':radio').on('change', function () {
        $("#occa_slct").val(0);
        $("#occa_slct").change();
        var title = $(this).val(); // Get radio value
        if ($(this).attr('id') === 'theme2') {
            $('.occ_select').addClass('l').removeClass('off');
        } else { //...otherwise status of radio is off
            $('.occ_select').removeClass('l').addClass('off');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this. This will work.

### $('#occassion').prop('selectedIndex',0);

Hope this helps!!!